# How to send string data from Activity to started Service onclick method?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have one activity and service. I have three button on app. One of is `Start` to start Service the other is `Test` to send Service "Test" string the other is `Stop` to stop service.

I can start and stop service without any problem but when i try to send string i tried Intent but cannot find any way for this. I also tried `onStartCommand()` but cannot fire that method too..

What you can suggest?

Here my Activity

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    serviceIntent = Intent(applicationContext, MyService::class.java)
}



fun sendLogin(view: View){
    startService(serviceIntent)
    if (isMyServiceRunning(MyService::class.java)){
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}

fun sendTest(view: View){ //TRY TO SEND "TEST" 
    val intent = Intent(this, MyService::class.java)
    val msj = "TEST"
    intent.putExtra("key", msj)
    applicationContext.startService(intent);
}

fun sendLogout(view: View){ //Stop service
    stopService(serviceIntent)
    if (!isMyServiceRunning(MyService::class.java)){
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}

private fun isMyServiceRunning(serviceClass: Class<*>): Boolean { //Checking app is started or not
    val manager = getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
    for (service in manager.getRunningServices(Int.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.name == service.service.className) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Here my service

```
private inner class MessageRequestHandler() : Handler()   {
    override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
        when (msg.what) {
            SEND_MESSAGE_FLAG -> {
                val bundle = Bundle()
                bundle.putString("key", stringMessage)
                val mesg = Message.obtain(null, SEND_MESSAGE_FLAG)
                mesg.obj = bundle
                try {
                    msg.replyTo.send(mesg)
                } catch (e: RemoteException) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Error: " + e.message)
                }
            }
        }

        super.handleMessage(msg)
    }

}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int { //Cannot fire this...
    stringMessage = intent?.extras?.getString("key").toString()
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
}

private val messageMessenger: Messenger = Messenger(MessageRequestHandler())
override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder {
    return messageMessenger.binder
}
```

Thanks

Comment: when ate you trying to send string??, on starting the service, on stoppng or when testing??

Comment: @RishabhRitweek sendTest method

Comment: @saulyasar you can use `broadcastreceivers` or library like `eventbus`

Comment: @ruben can yo give example?

Comment: are you not getting a call to onStartCommand() when sendTestMethod() is executed?

Comment: @RishabhRitweek no , cannot fire that method when execute sendTestMethod...

Comment: can u once try passng application conext instead of activity(this)? i hope that sendTest is being called once u click d button

Comment: @Rishabh Ritweek Where do you mean?

Comment: In sendTest, when u start the service.. i dont see any reason why ur OnStartCommand wont be triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check, [message passing is easy using EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). Here's your solution:

```
//Define Event Class
class MessageEvent(val someString: String)
```

Main Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    private lateinit var serviceIntent: Intent

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        serviceIntent = Intent(applicationContext, MessageService::class.java)
    }
    
    fun sendLogin(view: View){
        startService(serviceIntent)
        if (isMyServiceRunning(MessageService::class.java)){
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    fun sendTest(view: View){
        //Post Events
        EventBus.getDefault().post(MessageEvent("TEST"))
    }

    fun sendLogout(view: View){
        stopService(serviceIntent)
        if (!isMyServiceRunning(MessageService::class.java)){
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    }

    private fun isMyServiceRunning(serviceClass: Class<*>): Boolean {
        val manager = getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
        for (service in manager.getRunningServices(Int.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.name == service.service.className) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

And Service class

```
class MessageService : Service() {

    private val TAG: String? = "InService"

    private inner class MessageRequestHandler() : Handler()   {
        override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
            super.handleMessage(msg)
        }

    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    fun onMessageEvent(event: MessageEvent?) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onMessageEvent: " + event?.someString)
    }

    override fun onStart(intent: Intent?, startId: Int) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId)

        //subscribe to EventBus
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    private val messageMessenger: Messenger = Messenger(MessageRequestHandler())
    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder {
        return messageMessenger.binder
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        //Unsubscribe to EventBus
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for example  I really did what you write but it returned me empty string... Actually i have two different apps and this is my Server app when press button i want to pass string to Server and send that string to client app.  can start service then press SendTest button hen from client side i can bind server and when i try to click Get message i got empty string . Here is my question maybe you can see big picture here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64478498/how-to-send-remote-service-message-onclick-via-messenger

Comment: did you add the `EventBus` dependency in `build.gradle`?

Comment: As you have described it is a single app and it is working fine for me. do you get anything in `logcat`? the other question you've asked is another thing

Comment: sure i added in build.gradle and no i didn't get any message from logcat. I added  random number creator function to onStartCommand() to be sure service is on but also it's not firing that too...

Comment: Please check the working android studio project code in this github link https://github.com/mzc1986/ActivityServiceMessage

Comment: I have one difference in Service onMessageEvent i'm using event?.message @ruben please you can remove code from github

Comment: Dear @ruben actually when i press the button sendTest i want to send TEST string to Service and assign in public string variable then i want to use that variable...

Comment: @saulyasar removed. yes create a local variable in service and use that variable. If the main question is working please mark the answer as solved.

Comment: I also tried in new android project and when i press button i got the message 'No subscribers registered for event class'

Comment: have you subscribed to eventbus in your service? this is the line `EventBus.getDefault().register(this);`

Comment: sure onStart method.. basically i copied and pasted what you wrote on your github code check please https://github.com/sauliko/SendMessageFromActivityToService

Comment: you forgot to declare the `Service` in the `AndroidManifest` !

Comment: I changed manifest as in this example and worked thanks man for your help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295912/eventbus-comunication-between-activity-and-service

Comment: But in my main application still cannot pass data to service and i saw in the log this 'Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED dat=package: flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.apps.photos/.account.full.SyncAccountsForLoginBroadcastReceiver what it can be? '

Comment: you mean is it the other question ? if it's between two application that will be inter process communication. it might be different, i have to check.

Comment: thanks for all helps i solved problem it not worked before because in Manifest i didn't give also permission for internet and networking when i'm giving that it worked.. Thanks!

Comment: @saulyasar i don't agree though. For `Activity` and `Service` communication you don't need `internet` permission in the `manifest`